# Flutter - How to highlight selected text in PDF file?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf

I need to highlight selected text in PDF files using different colors. I am using this [native_pdf_view](https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view) to view pdf, which doesn't have a select and highlight option. The attachment shows the desired output.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, You can't select text in native_pdf_view.

It render pdf page as the image.

see https://github.com/rbcprolabs/packages.flutter/issues/26